How would I extract from xml the value of "xml:id" in python using ElementTree into a dataframe
I'm currently in the process of wrangling bibliographic information from an XML structure into, literally, almost anything else useable. My final move is to pull the value of the "xml:id" attribute and add that to my nice dataframe. I've got everything else working nicely in ElementTree and pandas in python.
eg: I want to pull "Kagawa2014" from biblStruct below:
<biblStruct type="book" xml:id="Kagawa2014" corresp="http://zotero.org/users/local/fmahZILk/items/EAK64XAU">
    <monogr>
#blahblah
    </monogr>
</biblStruct>

I've tried a few things I've found on stack overflow:
for biblStruct in root.findall('.//tei:biblStruct', namespace):
    id_elem = biblStruct.attrib('xml:id')

and received TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
and this, which I had a lot of hope for:
for biblStruct in root.findall('.//tei:biblStruct', namespace):
    id_elem = biblStruct.get('{http://w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id')
    id_text = id_elem.text if id_elem is not None else ''
    xmlID.append(id_text)

    
data = {
    'XML_ID':xmlID
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

This returned a DF that just counted the biblStructs (the correct number) (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4, etc etc)
also:
for biblStruct in root.findall('.//tei:biblStruct', namespace):
    id_elem = biblStruct.get('{http://w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id')
    xmlID.append(id_elem)

    
data_again = {
    'XML_ID': xmlID
    }
df_again = pd.DataFrame(data_again)
print(df_again)

This returned a DF like the above, only now, TWICE as many! Like magic.

I managed to make it work. to extract the value of the xml:id from the snippet
    xml_id = biblStruct.get('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id',
'')

My first attempts were missing the '' at the end.

Can be done using lxml.
The default xml namespace is not declared in the document but used in the attribute. The namespace can be added to the namespaces dict anyway and the attribute found out of the element using xpath
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('/home/lmc/tmp/tmp2.xml')
ns = {'xml': 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'}
ele = tree.xpath('//biblStruct', namespaces=ns)[0]
print(ele.xpath('@xml:id')[0])

Result
'Kagawa2014'


Thank you so much. That may also be useful in filtering out some other values.

.xpath() is lxml only. Also, don't you need the namespaces=ns arg?

@DanielHaley thanks for pointing out the missing parameter. And yes, xpath() is lxml and also ElementTree does not support @* xpath expressions so @k-mc, my answer won't work with ElementTree

@LMC, I still appreciate the time! and I'll tuck that away for future projects!

This question is difficult to answer. Not because it's complicated, but because your samples (both XML and Python) are incomplete so we can't run what you have. We don't have a minimal and reproducible sample; we have to start from scratch.
I digress...
What you're trying to get is an attribute value. Not an element value (so there's not going to be any .text property).
You were (probably) close with your original attempt (untested because I don't have time to start from scratch). .attrib is a dictionary so you access it like one...
for biblStruct in root.findall('.//tei:biblStruct', namespace):
    id_attr = biblStruct.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id']

Or (preferable in my opinion)...
id_attr = biblStruct.get('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id')

Edit: After looking at your last example closer, it appears what I did with .get() is what you did. If you're not getting the attribute value, something else must be wrong (but I don't know what because I can't reproduce).

thank you for your time in responding. and my apologies, I did trim too much. Messing about with it, I got the info i wanted doing something close to my first attempt.
